# How Do I View Web Server Logs for Dot Net Core Project on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, visual-studio, logging, .net-core, server

I am new to web apps on Visual Studio and am using VS 2019 Community Edition on Mac. I have a Dot Net Core app with C Sharp and React and have written basic client-server interactions. While the app runs, I have no idea how to see requests coming in to the server to debug what is happening on the server side. My question is how to access a console which reads out:

- The URL/API endpoint being hit, with timestamp
- The payload sent to the endpoint
- The HTTP Response rendered by the server

Thanks for your help.